# Reading only the first value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to add the below body to JSON. But I only see one value is being added.

```
json = { "Myname":"Nate",  }
```

Adding the below code:

```
Body = Myproperty: [{
  "vehicle": "car",
  "color": "Red"
}, {
  "name": "van",
  "color": "white"
}, {
  "name": "Truck",
  "color": "Blue"
}]
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Myproperty.length; i++) {
  json.mycarname = Body.Myproperty[i].name;
  json.mycolor = Body.Myproperty[i].color;
}
```

The end result should look like this:

```
{
  "Myname": "Nate",
  mycarname: "car",
  "mycolor": "Red"
},
{
  "Myname": "Nate",
  mycarname: "van",
  "mycolor": "white"
},
{
  "Myname": "Nate",
  mycarname: "Truck",
  "mycolor": "Blue"
}
```

Comment: Please format your code using the code block instead of single-line formatting.

Comment: Only see last value of the Array being added

Comment: Your `json` is a single object. You just replace its value in the loop. That's why you see only one value being added.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You're setting the value to be the current index objects value. This will always show the last value because you're overwriting it.

Comment: sidenote, which is likely an error of the copy/paste job, the `Body` object is not enclosed in `{}`, which throws a syntax error;

Comment: can you please be more specific and try to write new code for adding all the value in the array?

Comment: @karan your `json` variable is an object, and objects are not the same thing as an array.

Comment: Instead of `json.mycarname = Body.Myproperty[i].name; json.mycolor = Body.Myproperty[i].color;` TRY >> `json.cars = {}';` before the loop, then in the loop `json.cars[mycarname] = Body.Myproperty[i].name;
  json.cars[mycolor] = Body.Myproperty[i].color;`

Comment: Also, what would you want the end object to look like?

Comment: { "Myname":"Nate",  mycarname:"car","mycolor":"Red"},{ "Myname":"Nate",  mycarname:"van","mycolor":"white"},{ "Myname":"Nate",  mycarname:"Truck","mycolor":"Blue"}

Comment: for the result structure you are asking for json cannot be a single object since it can only have one `mycarname` and `mycolor` property. only way to have the json similar to what you are asking for is arrays of objects with a key like mycars; would result in something like `json = {mycars: [{ "Myname":"Nate", mycarname:"car","mycolor":"Red"},{ "Myname":"Nate", mycarname:"van","mycolor":"white"},{ "Myname":"Nate", mycarname:"Truck","mycolor":"Blue"}]}`

Comment: can you please send the to code to get the output in an array?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do something like this:

```js
var myName = "Nate";

var Body = [{
    "name": "car",
    "color": "Red"
  },
  {
    "name": "van",
    "color": "white"
  },
  {
    "name": "Truck",
    "color": "Blue"
  }
]

var json = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Body.length; i++) {
  json.push({
    "Myname": myName,
    "mycarname": Body[i].name,
    "mycolor": Body[i].color
  });
}

console.log(json)
```

The idea is to loop over the entries you want to add and push them into the `json` array.